# Is there a difference in the way memory is zeroed by calloc and memset?

Tags: c, malloc, heap-memory, stack-memory, calloc

suppose i have a structure :

```
typedef struct
{
   int a;
   struct x;
   struct *x2;
   char *s;
}global_struct;
```

I have a pointer which points to the memory equal to size of structure :

```
ptr = calloc(sizeof(global_struct),1);
```

I actually don't want to allocate memory on the heap and so id declare a variable of the structure as :

```
global_struct var_struct1;
```

and i am using memset to initialize the memory to zero.

```
memset(&var_struct1,0,sizeof(var_struct1))
```

My code gives segmentation fault when i do this.

I want to know if there's any reason as to why would this fail and under what scenarios?

Comment: You never `malloc` in your question. Are you missing something?

Comment: The code shown should work fine.If you are doing just what is shown then Segfault is from somewhere else not in shown code.

Comment: This is the only difference in the code. i have modified it to show more details

Comment: There's no reason for your code to crash (at least due to what you posted so far). Your `memset` call is perfectly fine. The problem must be elsewhere. Are you by any chance returning a pointer to a local variable from your function to the calling code?

Comment: As a side note, the construct that is foreseen by the standard to initialize a variable is an initializer, `= { 0 }` should suffice in your case. On a weirdo architecture that has null pointers that are not all-bit-zero, this could be the only correct way. On such architectures `calloc` or `memset` would not be correct.

Comment: No i am not doing anything like that.

Comment: What is your platform? OS, compiler ...

Comment: Is `var_struct1` a variable with local scope to a function that is returning its address?

Comment: Make sure you initialize pointers to NULL, or any other valid pointer value, manually after memset. NULL may not be presented with `0` bytes on your system.

Comment: m using gcc compiler on ubuntu... and var_struct1 has global scope

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a difference in the way memory is zeroed by calloc and memset?

No. In fact, calloc likely calls memset internally.

> I want to know if there's any reason as to why would this fail and under what scenarios?

No. You have the order of the calloc parameters wrong, it should be `calloc(1, sizeof(global_struct));`. Although in this case, the ordering of the parameters actually does not matter.

> My code gives segmentation fault when i do this.

The problem is likely elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

There can be a difference.  On a vms system, one of the idle time things that can happen is pages in the free list can be zeroed, and moved to a zeroed free list, so that some of the cost behind that calloc may be hidden.   Your milage may vary.